# I just cant figure out why my code throws a syntax error when I add int() to a input

Tags: python, python-3.x

first off here is my code:

```
def main():
    def add(x,y):

        return x + y

    def subtract(x,y):

        return x - y

    def multiple(x,y):

        return x * y

    def divide(x,y):

        return x / y

user_choice = int(input("Choose calculation: 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4. multiple \n")

dog = int(input("Enter first number: "))
cat = int(input("Enter second number: "))


if user_choice == '1':
   print(dog,"+",cat,"=", add(dog,cat))

elif user_choice == '2':
   print(dog,"-",cat,"=", subtract(dog,cat))

elif user_choice == '3':
   print(dog,"*",cat,"=", multiply(dog,cat))

elif user_choice == '4':
   print(dog,"/",cat,"=", divide(dog,cat))
else:
   print("Invalid input")

main()
while True:
    restart = input("Would you like to restart? (y/n)")
    if restart == 'y':
         main()

    elif restart == 'n':
        print('have a nice day!')
        break
    else:
        print("invalid input. Please enter y or n.")
```

So i built a pretty simple calculator that does addition, multiplication, subtraction, and division. Now, the problem is when I run this exact code I get a syntax error calling out line 20

```
dog = int(input("Enter first number: "))
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I couldn't figure out why this line was wrong since i looked at another small program i built and it had basically the same line. After fiddling around a bit I managed to fix the program, by removing int() from the user_choice input. I just want to know why exactly this fixed that problem? and is there a different reason that line wasnt working? Thanks for any input!

Comment: BTW, the built-in `operator` module already has the `add`, `sub`, `mul` and `truediv` functions, so you don't really need to write your own.

Comment: in `user_choice = int(input(` line you open two parethesis, but close only one.

Comment: Use an IDE, you won't have these kind of issues

Comment: thank you for telling me about the operator module, that would definitely simplify this haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a bracket at the end of this line (fixed below):

```
user_choice = int(input("Choose calculation: 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4. multiple \n"))
```

Also, the `multiply` function is misspelled.

Just noticed another one, the `if user_choice` checks should be checking for ints not strings `if user_choice == 1` not `if user_choice == '1'`

Comment: We have a close reason for just this sort of thing: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer! I cant believe I had just simple mistakes like forgetting a bracket. I definitely would of kept passing over removing the string from  if user_choice == "1" so again thank you.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Ah Im brand new to stack overflow but I think I have just accepted the answer haha. yeah I see a lot of people mentioning using an IDE so I think i might check PyCharm out or just try out IDLE.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce wow good to know! Definitely gonna check out PyCharm then.